# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes during boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, wubi

I installed Ubuntu using the Windows Installer (Wubi).  When I start my computer and select Ubuntu, my screen goes black and I see a blinking cursor at the top left of the screen. I have waited an hour, but nothing happens.  I have tried restarting the computer multiple times, but the same thing always happens.  Windows works fine though.

I am trying to use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I also tried to install Ubuntu using a USB drive, but it would hang during the initial start-up.  It would print "voltage table 0x50 unknown" and freeze.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I need Ubuntu for work.